# Predicate and quantifiers_discrete

Tags: discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic

Consider the predicate ∀x A(x) → ∃x B(x)

i Just want to know is this predicate always true ?
Reason i think "∀x A(x)" will always be false and hence making the predicate always TRUE ..!!
let A(x)=x is even
B(x)=x is odd
now there won't be case when All x will be "even" making it false..please correct me

Comment: When you say " is this predicate always true ?" you are asking if the formula of predicate logic is *valid*, that means: "true in every interpretation". Thus, from the fact that is it true in a (suitable chiosen) interpretation, you are not licensed that this is so in **every** interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

No, the predicate can be false. Consider $A(x)$ as $x=x$ and $B(x)$ as $x\neq x$. Then your predicate is false.

Comment: See this question "check if ∀x(P (x) → Q(x)) and ∀xP (x) →∀xQ(x) are logically equivalent." they both are not equivalent because the solution said that "∀xP (x)" of  RHS part will always be false ..,making RHS True and not LHS true

Answer (score 1):

> Reason i think "∀x A(x)" will always be false and hence making the predicate always TRUE ..!!

$\forall x A(x)$ will not *always* be false, even if maybe it will *usually* be false. For it to be true, you have to pick $A(x)$ to be something really stupid that is always true, such as "$x = x$" or simply $\textsf{True}$.

> let A(x)=x is even B(x)=x is odd now there won't be case when All x will be "even" making it false..

You are right for the *specific* example of $A(x)$ being "$x$ is even" and $B(x)$ being "$x$ is odd", that the formula comes out true. But for other predicates $A$, $B$, it can come out true. So you haven't shown that it is **always true**. In fact it is sometimes false, as has already been pointed out.

Comment: See this question "check if ∀x(P (x) → Q(x)) and ∀xP (x) →∀xQ(x) are logically equivalent." they both are not equivalent because the solution said that "∀xP (x)" of RHS part will always be false ..,making RHS True and not LHS true

Comment: @sourav Are you trying to ask a new, different question? Click "Ask Question" at the top of the page.